# Not working SQL query What is wrong on code angular MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, angular, typescript-typings

**Working fine Below query**

let forbiddenExistQuery = `SELECT * FROM forbidden_words WHERE id = ${activeforbiddenWord.forbidden_word_id}`;
let IdExist = await pool.query(forbiddenExistQuery)

**Same thing i am doing on another table name just name change nothing else name is "shrt-campaign-prod-catalog-categories" but not working not given any error also how can i fix below issue.**

let shrtExistQuery = `SELECT * FROM shrt-campaign-prod-catalog-categories    WHERE id = ${activeforbiddenWord.forbidden_word_id}`;
let IdExist = await pool.query(shrtExistQuery)

---

**Any one guide me what wrong with below query.**

Comment: May be no data on where clause condition. Please try without where clause. like:  let shrtExistQuery = SELECT * FROM shrt-campaign-prod-catalog-categories; let IdExist = await pool.query(shrtExistQuery)

Comment: @jainvikram444 yes i have try without where clause but still not working thanks.

Comment: Please, try in MySQL and check data is available?

Comment: @jainvikram444 I have checked on MYSQL Given result yes.                                  
**  177 row(s) returned 0.0013 sec / 0.0022 sec **

Answer (score 0):

**Yes Working fine i have fixed my self.**

let shrtExistQuery = 'SELECT * FROM `shrt-campaign-prod-catalog-categories` WHERE id=' + activeforbiddenWord.forbidden_word_id + ' ';

let IdExist = await pool.query(shrtExistQuery);

**i think there is some table name in - not able to get record so i have added on single quote now working fine thanks Darshan malani**

Answer (score 0):

I think there is issues for - concatenation for single quote string value.

Comment: Yes may i am not sure.

Comment: this "answer" should be a comment